# PHP mySQL query, joining another table but need all rows to be fetched

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Bit more of a description:

I've got a main table as an example

```
tblmain

fldID | fldTitle | fldCompleted | fldCompleted2
1     | Hello    | TRUE         | FALSE
2     | World    | TRUE         | TRUE
```

Then I'm joining another table as follows

```
tbltojoin

fldID | fldMainID | fldName | fldOrder | fldDeliver
13    | 2         | Item 1  | TRUE     | TRUE
14    | 2         | Item 2  | TRUE     | FALSE
```

I'm wanting to join these to show the false rows but also show the true row if the tblmain has some FALSEs in tbltojoin.

So my desired output is as follows

```
World

Name   | Completed | Completed 2 | Ordered | Delivered
Item 1 | Yes       | Yes         | Yes     | Yes
Item 2 | Yes       | Yes         | Yes     | No
```

Hopefully this makes sense, so even though I'm looking for FALSE items I still want the completed row from tbltojoin to show.

I've tried various joins but I only end up managing to show FALSE results.

If I've missed out any important info just let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleasen use this query

```
SELECT  
  fldName  Name
   ,IF(fldCompleted='TRUE','yes','no') Completed 
  ,IF(fldCompleted2='TRUE','yes','no') 'Completed 2'
  , IF(`fldOrder`='TRUE','yes','no') Ordered 
  , IF(`fldDeliver`='TRUE','yes','no') Delivered
FROM tblmain m inner join tbltojoin t on  m.fldID = t.fldMainID
ORDER by t.fldID;
```

To get

```
Name    Completed   Completed 2     Ordered     Delivered
Item 1  yes         yes             yes         yes
Item 2  yes         yes             yes          no
```

but fldTitle aka World can''t be done like you wanted.

I would add it to the select and then show it in whatever language  you use.

I would also add fldID from tblmain to the select, sp that ypu can check when it changes-